# Using proj4 and EPSG code to transform into different coordinate system

Tags: javascript, leaflet, coordinate-systems, proj

I have coordinates in  `EPSG:25833`, which is `UTM`, zone 32N.
I want to transform them into `EPSG:3857`, WebMercator. The [documentation](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js) says

```
var firstProjection = 'PROJCS["NAD83 / Massachusetts Mainland",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",42.68333333333333],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",41.71666666666667],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",41],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-71.5],PARAMETER["false_easting",200000],PARAMETER["false_northing",750000],AUTHORITY["EPSG","26986"],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH]]';
var secondProjection = "+proj=gnom +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=6300000 +y_0=6300000 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs";

proj4(firstProjection,secondProjection,[2,5]);
```

Is it possible to pass only a EPSG string as `firstProjection` and `secondProjection`? Passing i.e. for `EPSG:25833` which is `UTM 32N` contains already all the needed information. Why is there a need to pass to do this

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:25833"] = "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs";
```

Using this definition restricts me too. What if `EPSG:25833` changes to another `EPSG`? Then I have to update this `+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs` too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proj4js is distributed with the following coordinate systems,

```
export default function(defs) {
  defs('EPSG:4326', "+title=WGS 84 (long/lat) +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=degrees");
  defs('EPSG:4269', "+title=NAD83 (long/lat) +proj=longlat +a=6378137.0 +b=6356752.31414036 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=degrees");
  defs('EPSG:3857', "+title=WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs");

  defs.WGS84 = defs['EPSG:4326'];
  defs['EPSG:3785'] = defs['EPSG:3857']; // maintain backward compat, official code is 3857
  defs.GOOGLE = defs['EPSG:3857'];
  defs['EPSG:900913'] = defs['EPSG:3857'];
  defs['EPSG:102113'] = defs['EPSG:3857'];
}
```

> https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/blob/master/lib/global.js

All the other coordinate systems need to be defined by the user. Compare with PROJ4 C library that is distributed with a EPSG database,...

and that is the reason you can't pass just a EPSG code, unless it's defined elsewhere.

Just a note,

You can declare, for example,

```
Proj4js.defs["ETRS89 UTM32"] = "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs";
```

instead of

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:25833"] = "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs";
```

And, then, an alias

```
Proj4js.MYEPSG = Proj4js.defs["EPSG:25833"]
```

Comment: If the UTM Zone changes the definition needs update too. But the UTM zone is contained in the EPSG Code... But in order to read the UTM Zone from the EPSG code, I need to decode the EPSG code... I use this library for that https://github.com/derhuerst/epsg-index

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wasn't aware of that EPSG DB for proj4js.